# How to read X-RateLimit HTTP header from Watson API response in Java

Tags: java, http, http-headers, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm working on a Java chatbot application using the Watson Conversation Service and I want to retrieve the information about my API limit.

API Reference states:
The response to each HTTP request includes headers you can use to determine whether you are close to the rate limit: X-RateLimit-Reset: the time the current timer expires (in UNIX epoch time) X-RateLimit-Remaining: the number of requests remaining in the current time window X-RateLimit-Limit: the total number of requests allowed within the time window
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?java#rate-limiting

I am interested in the values for Limit and Remaining in order to generate a warning if the remaining value is lower then a particular portion. Browsing through the code of the Java-SDK (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/) I couldn't find a way to retrieve this information from the message response. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Erik, I think you are right that there is no proper way to get the rate limit information using the current Java SDK.  You should open an issue against the Java SDK with the information you have collected above requesting this feature.